# Constraint/Autolayout bar hidden, Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

In my storyboard file, I would like to add constraints, but the button to insert constraint is not shown! Any idea how to get it back?

Comment: Some screenshots would be nice! Also check your storyboard is using autolayout on the property inspector! In ios 6 the autolayout buttons should be located at the bottom right of the workspace.

Comment: It's not, because I am using UIScrollView, and you're supposed to turn it off...

Comment: Well obviously the autolayout buttons would be hidden then...when you turn it off, all existing constraints are removed also, by the way.

Comment: So how do i add constrains, or is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: You can add them programmatically, although that would be somewhat cumbersome, and I think it has the same effect as enabling autolayout in your storyboard. Where did you see that you are not supposed to use autolayout with UIScrollView?

Comment: Youtube, because I wasn't really sure how to use them. Every video i clicked said to disable auto layout

Comment: I think that's because it's hard to get things right - stuff may be floating on top of the scrolled view instead of be scrolled with the content view. Try this one though. http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/ios-how-to-use-uiscrollview-with-autolayout-pure-autolayout-approach-multiple-smaller-views/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Make sure auto layout is enabled if you want to use the auto layout controls.

Autolayout Enabled:
[image: Autolayout enabled]

Autolayout Disabled: Note the controls are missing.

[image: Autolayout disabled]

If you're looking to use auto layout with UIScrollView it should probably be asked in another question.  But very briefly, when using auto layout, the place most people trip up is that UIScrollView determines its content size based on your constraints within the scrollview.  If those are set right, you should be good to go.

Good luck.

Answer (score 17):

Quiting Xcode and reopening worked for me.

Comment: Seems to be a bug, so this actually worked for me too (exist in Xcode version 11.2.1). Wonder if it's a autolayout bug perhaps...?

Comment: I think its an Xcode GUI logic state bug.  I think they probably have some logic where they aren't ensuring the auto layout constraints icon is showing for all cases where it should.

Comment: Agree. Definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found that sometimes constraints are not shown when wantsLayer property is checked in the Interface Builder. (only on OSX, not on iOS)

Answer (score 0):

Quit and reopen. I found out that works the best in Xcode 11 and above. there is no "Auto layout" click option in Xcode 11 so just quit and reopen